# Can Java Applets that I added to my security sitelist only run in sandbox mode?

Tags: java, security, applet

I have a Java JApplet that should execute the command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar acceleration_de.jar");
```

If I run the java file in Compiler it execute this command. If I run it in browser and I have added this local page to my java security sitelist (white list) it does not execute this command. Is it because Applets are in general not allowed to run this command or is it because the Applet does only run in sandbox? Will it be able to run this command if I offical sign it?

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar acceleration_de.jar");` Why on Earth use `exec` to run a Jar?  See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Comment: What makes ProcessBuilder better than exec?

Comment: Read the linked article, then implement it, then realize that `ProcessBuilder` does part of the recommendations for you (or at least makes it easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to request [all-permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/manifest.html#permissions) and sign your applet. You don't need an official certificate for it, if you put it in the sitelist.

Comment: Of course avoiding to execute something, especially if it is another Java application should be considered first.